# Google Static Map API - Exceed usage limit detection

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

According to the documentation requesting a map from Google (via the Static Map API) when you have exceeded the usage limit displays an 'error' image.  This is okay I guess but what I really want to do is detect the error so I can log something meaningful and alert the team.

Does anybody know if anything is returned in the RequestHeader to confirm this error.  I can see from the documentation there is an 'X-Staticmap-API-Warning' key but its unclear if this is populated in this case.

Of course we'll be monitoring the usage via the Developer Console, but it would be good if we didn't have to rely on our customers reporting a problem should we see a spike.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP-status of the image will be 403 when you see the error-image.

But that wouldn't help you much, because an `<img/>` doesn't have a property which gives you the HTTP-status.

Possible solution(works when the static map does have a size different to `100x100` ):

The error-image does have a size of 100x100, observe the onload-event and when the `naturalWidth`  and `naturalHeight` is `100`, do something:

```
<img src="staticmapurl"     
     onload="if(this.naturalWidth==this.naturalHeight==100){/*do something*/}"
/>
```

But note: there is also a quota for users, when google returns the error-image it must not be related to the quota of your project

Comment: I'm using several images of various scales to make a montage saving the final output to blob storage.  Because of this I'm making the call server-side so getting the http-status isn't a problem. I must say, I'm surprised Google are using a 403 as this isn't a authentication issue.  A 429 would have been better suited IMO

Comment: have you witnessed a 403 error when exceeding the quota?  I ask because the documentation clearly states 4XX errors are only returned for invalid requests.